# Пунктуация в предложении

Tags: прописная-строчная, пунктуация

Помогите, пожалуйста, определиться с пунктуацией в этом предложении:
Первая часть книги призвана ответить на вопрос «почему?».

1. Уместна ли точка после закрывающей кавычки?
2. Не нужно ли двоеточие перед кавычками?
3. Не следует ли слово "почему?" написать с заглавной буквы?

Благодарю заранее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первая часть книги призвана ответить на вопрос «почему?».
Думаю, Ваше написание вполне корректно.

1)Точка нужна, чтобы закончить повествовательное предложение. [СОЧЕТАНИЯ ЗНАКОВ ПРЕПИНАНИЯ](http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/55.htm)
Розенталь, §135. Кавычки и другие знаки
4.  Если перед закрывающими кавычками стоит вопросительный или восклицательный знак, то тот же самый знак не повторяется после кавычек; неодинаковые же знаки, если они требуются по условиям контекста, ставятся перед закрывающими кавычками и после них. Например: Читали ли вы статью в «Известиях» «Куда мы идем?» Ср.: Бойцы двинулись в атаку с криком «Вперед!». Когда был выдвинут лозунг «Вся власть Советам!»?

2,3)Двоеточие перед кавычками и  слово "Почему?" с заглавной буквы можно написать, если Вы оформляете как прямую речь. Если же имеете в виду процитированное слово или слово в необычном значении, то со строчной буквы и без двоеточия:§ 153. Кавычками подчеркивается чисто грамматическая необычность употребления слов, например в случае, когда в качестве членов предложения употребляются части речи или целые обороты, не  предназначенные для выражения данных функций: «Хочешь?», «давай ты» звучало в моих ушах и производило какое-то о
пьянение; я ничего и никого не видел, кроме Сонечки (Л. Т.); От его приветливого «я вас ждал» она повеселела(Б. П.).
   И то и другое корректно.

Comment: Именно так я и думала. Спасибо за объяснение.

Answer (score 2):

> > 1) Уместна ли точка после закрывающей кавычки?

Вопрос до конца не ясен. Неоднократно высказывались мнения (на той же gramota.ru), что точка после закрывающей кавычки не ставится, если перед ней стоит вопросительный или восклицательный знак (иногда упоминали еще многоточие). Однако конкретных рекомендация в авторитетных источниках на этот счет найти не удалось. Поэтому точку, думаю, следует сохранить.

> > 2) Не нужно ли двоеточие перед кавычками?
> > 3) Не следует ли слово "почему?" написать с заглавной буквы?

Здесь тоже не до конца разобрались. Но лучше и безопаснее, думаю, именно так, с двоеточием и кавычками, т.е. оформляя как прямую речь.

> > Вопрос № 201003  
> > Уважаемые господа, верно ли я написала: А на вопрос "а как?", я не слышала ответа ни разу. Или правильно будет: А на вопрос: "А как?", - я не слышала ответа ни разу. Или это вообще на усмотрение трудящихся? Что такое в данном случае "а как"? Уж не прямая речь, во всяком случае, мне кажется... Спасибо!
> > Розалия Декель
> > Ответ справочной службы русского языка
> > Грамматически это прямая речь. Корректно: _А на вопрос «А как?» я не слышала ответа ни разу.

У меня есть некоторые сомнения в безусловности это рекомендации, поскольку встречается оформление **не** как прямой речи, но тут тот же случай. Без авторитетного источника рекомендовать не могу.